# Find an $n$ not a power of a prime such that $n$ has 51 positive divisors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-counting-function

> Find an $n$ not a power of a prime such that $n$ has 51 positive divisors.

I'm not sure where to even start with this question. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: May I presume this is related to your studies of... elementary number theory?  What is a theorem or function you know that is similar?

Comment: **Hint:** Factor $51$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$51=3\cdot17$, therefore you can choose any primes $[p,q]$ and calculate $n=(p^{3-1})\cdot(q^{17-1})$.

For example, the smallest such value is $n=3^{3-1}\cdot2^{17-1}=3^{2}\cdot2^{16}=9\cdot65536=589824$.